# Looping ajax calls until button is pressed

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
document.getElementById("uploadUpdate").addEventListener("click", function() {
    intervalVarUpload = setInterval(function () {
        console.log("Updating table..");
        Object.keys(arrExplores).forEach(function (key) {
            if(arrExplores[key][2] != "Not"){
                //remoteArrUpdate makes a ajax call
                remoteArrUpdate(arrExplores[key][2], key);
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
    console.log("Interval started!");
});
```

---

```
document.getElementById("uploadStop").addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(intervalVarUpload);
});
```

---

```
function remoteArrUpdate(id, key) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://offcloud.com/api/remote/status',
        data: {'requestId' : id},
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(data) {
            arrExplores[key] = [arrExplores[key][0],key,data.status.requestId,data.status.status, data.status.fileSize];
             explorArrToTable();
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Failed!');
        }
    });
}
```

So, at the moment, a uploadUpdate button is clicked and an interval is started to go through an array and make a ajax on every object and update that object.  However, I don't want to use an interval because sometimes the next interval will start before the previous is finished and sometimes there is a long wait time.  I want the next interval to start as soon as the previous interval has either successfully or unsuccessfully finished all ajax calls, to start at the beginning of the array again and start making the same ajax calls, until the uploadStop button is pressed.  How would i change the two button functions to do this?

Comment: *"json calls"* - Do you mean "Ajax calls"?

Comment: Yes, thanks. updated/editted

Comment: Maybe have `removeArrUpdate()` return a promise, then in your loop push each promise into an array and use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (or the jQuery equivalent) to wait for them all to complete and restart the promise from there instead of using the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to mimic your ajax calls using a setTimeout. You could use it in your ajax success / failure. I think, you need some code refactoring to accomplish this. Hope this helps / point you in the right direction.

```js
var intervalVarUpload;
document.getElementById("uploadUpdate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  uploadUpdate();
});


function uploadUpdate() {
  //Start the Interval
  intervalVarUpload = setInterval(doSomething, 2000);
  console.log("Interval started!");
}

document.getElementById("uploadStop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Interval Stopped");
  //Clear the Interval
  clearInterval(intervalVarUpload);
});

function doSomething() {
  //Clear the Interval so as to hold on till the current method call is complete.
  clearInterval(intervalVarUpload);

  console.log("Updating table..");
  var arrExplores = {
    customArray: ["Yes", "Not", "Hello"]
  };
  Object.keys(arrExplores).forEach(function(key) {
    if (arrExplores[key][2] != "Not") {
      //remoteArrUpdate makes a json call
      remoteArrUpdate(arrExplores[key][2], key);
    }
  });
}

function remoteArrUpdate(id, key) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    //Consider as a ajax complete
    uploadUpdate();
  }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<button id="uploadUpdate">Upload Update</button>
<button id="uploadStop">Upload Stop</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into doing something like this